# Tabla de multiplicación en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual

Estoy tratando crear una tabla de multiplicación en C# que muestre los primeros dos resultados pares y que continué si presiono la tecla Enter, pero estoy teniendo problemas en declarar la tecla y en hacer que se detenga sin reiniciar el contador.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int numero, i, resultado,j;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CboOpcion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(CboOpcion.Text);
        }

        private void BtnMulti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(i=1;i<=9;i++){
                resultado = numero * i;
                listBox2.Items.Add(resultado);
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Se detiene en los primeros dos y al presionar enter aparecen los siguientes dos. Al mostrar hasta el 10 se cierra el programa

Comment: No coloques como comentario parte de tu pregunta. Editar la pregunta y agrega el texto.

Comment: para que hacer un for? si tenes el evento click?

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    int numero, i, resultado,j, contador = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CboOpcion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numero = Convert.ToInt32(CboOpcion.Text);
    }

    private void BtnMulti_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        contador =0;

            for(i=1;i<=9;i++){
            resultado = numero * i;

            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
               if (contador <= 2)
               {
                 listBox2.Items.Add(resultado);
                 contador++;
               }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}